# Preference window destroyed when closed - Glade, Gtk, Python

Tags: python, linux, gtk, glade

I am experiencing a problem with my program wherein when I close my preference window via the close button it will not reopen properly.

[image: Main Window with placeholder items]

I open the preference window by going "file>preferences" which works just fine...

[image: working preference window]

However when I close it via the close button in the top right...

[image: preference window with close]

It will no longer open properly. For the record the back button which I have connected to my close_pref_window function works just fine.

[image: broken preference window]

To open the window I go "file>preferences" which triggers a function that just preference_window.show_all() and to close it I call pref_window.hide(). I also have the delete_event connected to the same function as the back arrow so I don't understand why the one works and not the other. I am thinking that the close button destroys the window first and then calls the function... Any suggestions?

Comment: We will need to see your code. It's likely your `delete-event` handler is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a `return True` ? All the rest of the code is still not going to work if you let the delete_event run to the end .

Comment: In glade I have the delete_event connected to my `pref_window_hide(self, *args):` function. The issue I am having is instead of hiding it destroys the window. Is there maybe a way I can remove the close button from the window bar all together?

Comment: @DanielCopley look at @theGtknerd's comment. That part is important; without it, `delete-event` will think you want the default behavior, which is to destroy the window. This is why we are asking for the source code: we don't know if this is the actual problem or not. Your comment above is just reiterating the question; yes, we do understand your question, but the question by itself is not enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @andlabs how can I specifically tell the delete event not to execute its default action?

Comment: Look at @theGtkner's comment again; they tell you what to do.

Comment: @theGtknerd I figured this much, how am I able to stop the default action from executing. I connected the signals in glade so there is no connection in my actual code.

Comment: @DanielCopley Could you post your `pref_window_hide (self, *args):` function? @andlabs has repeatedly asked you and you appear to not hear or not want to. Warning, if you cannot give a reason for not posting your code and keep on asking for help (which I cannot provide currently), I will ignore all of your questions in the future.

Comment: Also please refer to the documentation. I do not know if you are using PyGTK or PyGObject, but either way the normal C GTK+ documentation is the first resort if the official docs don't explain. (And IIRC PyGObject tries to have good documentation that mirrors the normal ones...)

Comment: @theGtknerd I will post that function now. I didn't realize he was asking for it. It is only one line and its purpose is simply to hide the window. In glade I have its delete-event signal connected to this function. 
    `def pref_window_close(self, *args):`
       
        `self.preference_window.hide()`

Comment: @DanielCopley So now you need: `def pref_window_close (self, *args):` `self.preference_window.hide` `return True`. With return True on a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @theGtknerd and @andlabs for your help. As theGtknerd pointed out the delete-event signal will continue to execute its default action unless your function includes `return True` at the end.

```
def pref_window_close(self, *args):
    self.pref_window.hide()
    return True
```

Thanks again for the help :)

(I apologize my question was answered a while ago, I was just mis-reading their comments :P)